# HttpClient Request keeps returning 401 "No Client Cert" from the REST Service

Tags: c#, xamarin, httpclient, client-certificates, x509certificate2

I have a problem in Xamarin Forms making a HttpClient Post from the Iphone simulator with a .p12 certificate attached.  It keeps returning 401 "No Client Cert" from the REST Service.  I created a separate console C# application with the same code and it works fine, I get a 200 response from the server plus content which is expected.  The only difference I note is that the C# console application is using .NET Core 3.1 and the Xamarin Forms app is using .NET Standard 2.1 which is the latest.  I will paste the code below, any help is appreciated.

```
            string url = "https://ws.soa:8443/etav/jwt/encode";

            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2("billyDillMacBook.p12", "test");
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (o, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, null);
                var token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

Comment: a 500 is an error on the server.  You need to debug the server code, look at the logs, etc to determine what is wrong

Comment: Given that the server is erroring, you'll need to debug on the server side. On the server, log requests. Even though its "the same code", clearly what the server is receiving is different in some way. Find that difference. If it isn't fixable on the server, then add to question what the server sees in the requests - BOTH the working request from console, and the not-working request. Something about headers and/or the certificate perhaps.

Comment: It's actually returning a 401 "No client Cert"

Comment: please update your post and title so they reflect the actual error you are getting

Comment: what is `billyDillMacBook.p12` - is that supposed to be a path to a certificate file?

Comment: It's bundled in my application.

Comment: bundled how, exactly?  As a Resource, or an Asset, or what?  Please be specific.  And is it in your platform project or your shared Forms project?

Comment: It's bundled as a Resource under the IOS platform project.